# Android storing query result into a variable

Tags: java, android, sql

Like the title says, I am currently doing a project in Android Studio writing in Java and I am trying to store a query result in a variable. I know in normal Java this can be done easily with the use of a ResultSet however I am not having much luck figuring this one out. I have other queries which just return a boolean to check if the user exists.

```
public Boolean checkUser(String email, String password){
   SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getWriteableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = MyDB.rawQuery("Select * from users where email = ? and password = ?", new String[]{email, password});
   if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false
```

Is there a way to do it like the Java way result set ? I don't need an arraylist as i'm just retrieving an username for example. I just want to store it and use it at some point maybe put it in an TextView or whatever.

I have tried the following but to no avail.

```
public String getFirstName(String email){
    SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = MyDB.rawQuery("Select firstname from users where email ="+email+"",null);
    return cursor.toString();

}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements fit the SQLiteStatement class. [Quoting the developer guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement).

> Compiles an SQL statement into a reusable pre-compiled statement object.

The class is limited to returning 1x1 or single value result sets, but it is a result set nonetheless. Here's how you would implement it in your case.

```
private boolean checkUser(String email, String password) {
    sqLiteDatabase = new MyOpenHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();
    
    SQLiteStatement sqLiteStatement = sqLiteDatabase.
            compileStatement(String.format("select firstname from users where email='%s' and password='%s'", email, password));

    String qrdFirstname = sqLiteStatement.simpleQueryForString();
    //use again
    String confirmQrdFirstName = sqLiteStatement.simpleQueryForString();
    
    assert qrdFirstname.equals(confirmQrdFirstName);

    return confirmQrdFirstName != null;
}
```

As illustrated, you can proceed to use the resultset instance as much as you'd like, but, since the SQLiteStatement implements AutoCloseable, it's best to use trywith and assign it to a variable that you can then re-use.

```
private boolean checkUser(String email, String password) {
    sqLiteDatabase = new MyOpenHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();
    
    String qrdFirstname = null;

    try (SQLiteStatement sqLiteStatement = sqLiteDatabase.
            compileStatement(String.format("select firstname from users where email='%s' and password='%s'", email, password))) {

        qrdFirstname = sqLiteStatement.simpleQueryForString();
    }
    return qrdFirstname != null;
}
```